# How to retrieve async results from a Node.js VM script using ES7 syntax

Tags: node.js, async-await, babeljs, ecmascript-2016

I'm trying to implement a way to run "sequentially written" async JS code in a Node.js VM and gain access to the respective context objects. I try to use the coming ES7 `await` functionality, transpiled by `babel.js`.

As it seems to me, [script.runInContext()](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_script_runincontext_contextifiedsandbox_options) is run in the background, while the main loop continues, thus I can't reach the results from the VM's context.

My sample code is the following:

```
var vm = require('vm');
var request = require('request-promise');
var babel = require("babel-core");

// VM context object
var contextCache = { 
    context: { 
        request: request 
    } 
};

// ES 7 code
var code = "var res = await request('http://www.google.de')";

// Wrap the code
code = "(async function() { " + code + " })()";

// Transpile code ES7 -> ES5
var regeneratedCode = babel.transform(code, { "ast": false, "presets": ["stage-0"] }).code

// Create VM context
var vmContext = new vm.createContext(contextCache.context);

// Create virtual script
var script = new vm.Script(regeneratedCode);

// Run script
script.runInContext(vmContext, {displayErrors: true, timeout: 30000});

// Check if variable was set -> Is undefined
console.log(contextCache.context.res);
```

Is there a way to retrieve asynchronous results from context evaluations in a synchronous way?

References:

- https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html
- http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/
- http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/#options
- https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait

Comment: I would have to go with no, that isn't possible. If it can't be done in ES5 or ES2015, it also can't be done in ES7 transpiled to ES5 or ES2015 other than by making it synchronous rather than asynchronous.

Comment: Not sure if "it can't be done"... The code itself is correct and executes. It's just a matter of getting the results. I think the problem is that I have to wrap the ES7 code in an async IIF, which causes the unreachability IMHO...

Comment: well, no. the console.log is going to happen before the asynchronous action completes. it has nothing to do with reaching it. Try wrapping that console.log in a long setTimeout to see what i mean.

Comment: True, but if I execute standard ES5 without the transpiling and the then necessary IIF the code will be executed synchronously IMHO... Look at a similar example of what I'm trying to implement: https://tonicdev.com/tonic/city-forecast

Comment: Ah, i just realized why everyone's flipping out about this async/wait syntax. It makes this possible: http://pastebin.com/9hiEADe3 is that basically what you are trying to do? (i don't understand how the vm module works. so i instead ran it in my own sandbox that uses a require hook to compile down to ES5)

Comment: to get the result you are wanting, all of the code in your snippet would also have to be inside of an async function, otherwise you'll need to be able to attach a .then to the promise returned.

Comment: Found a solution, but this is kind of workaround, which means I can't use ` var response = ...` and instead I have to use `this.response = ...`, which is not exactly what I wanted...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way to get this working... Basically it's using the `this` variable for the context object inside the executed code, and calling a callback function from inside as the last operation:

```
var vm = require('vm');
var babel = require("babel-core");

// VM context object
var context = {
    require: require,
    callback: function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error.stack);
        } else {
            console.log(this.response);
        }
    }
};

// ES 7 code
var code = "var request = require('request-promise'); var response = await request({ url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://news.ycombinator.com', json: true })";

// Wrap the code
code = "'use strict'; async function run() { try { " + code.replace(/var /g, "this.") + "; this.callback(null); } catch(error) { this.callback(error); } }; run.apply(this)";

// Transpile code ES7 -> ES5
var regeneratedCode = babel.transform(code, { "ast": false, "presets": ["stage-0"] }).code;

// Create VM context
var vmContext = new vm.createContext(context);

// Create virtual script
var script = new vm.Script(regeneratedCode);

// Run script
script.runInContext(vmContext, {displayErrors: true, timeout: 30000});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
async function runScript(code, context = {}, options = {}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { timeout = 120 * 1000, breakOnSigint = true } = options;
    const script = new Script(`(async()=>{${code}})()`);
    script.runInContext(createContext({
      ...context,
      resolve,
      reject,
    }), {
      timeout,
      breakOnSigint,
    });
  });
}
```

demo

```
await runScript('some code; resolve();')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to know when the script ends if there's some async operations on the script.
We can execute the script on the vm in a Promise by attaching the resolve function of the promise to the context. Then on the script execute that resolve function attached on the context.
This guarantees you that after this promise is resolved you can now grab results of an async function.

```
const vm = require('vm');

(async () => {
  const sandbox = {
    a: 1
  };
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    sandbox.resolve = resolve;
    const code = 'Promise.resolve(2).then(result => {a = result; resolve();})';
    const script = new vm.Script(code);
    const context = new vm.createContext(sandbox);
    script.runInContext(context);
  });
  console.log(sandbox.a); // 2
})();
```

[Gist here](https://gist.github.com/seromenho/b23bfbabdefbbaa19ea7865b7af9a174)

Comment: Clever. Thanks! (though some explanation would be good to qualify as a good SO answer)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing `var`  with `this.` you can just remove `var`.

That would make the variable global to the context which is then accessible on the outside of the vm.